# Ruby on Rails selecting multiple rows for 2 id's

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I want to create a private messages system and I am having a bit trouble with selecting all the messages between two users.

if I have a table named messages with:

id - message id 
content - message content 
user_id - sender id 
to_id - to id

Messages Controller:

```
@from_user = User.find_by(username: params[:name])
@messages = Message.where(user: [@from_user, current_user], to_id: [current_user, @from_user])
```

Thank you!

Comment: What is wrong with your code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
from_id = @from_user.id
to_id = current_user.id

Message.where("
  (user_id = #{from_id} AND to_id = #{to_id})
  OR
  (user_id = #{to_id} AND to_id = #{from_id})
")
```